# How do I make PowerShell not treat # as the beginning of the comment?

Tags: powershell, escaping

I am new to PowerShell.

I am trying to run a perforce (p4) command from within my PowerShell script.

```
p4 -c MyWorkSpaceName sync -f //mydepot/Folder1/Folder2...#head
```

Unfortunately, PowerShell treats #head as a comment but `#head` has special meaning to p4 command.

How do I make PowerShell not treat `#` as the beginning of the comment? If possible, I would like to continue using `#` as comment marker in rest of my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before posting the question I found the answer. I thought I would still post it if someone stumbles upon it.

I looked up 
[about_Comment_Based_Help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819489.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and
[About Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-5.1).

` (Backtick, available as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> on PC keyboard) works as an escape sequence character.

The documentation at the links does not mention of escaping # character in particular, but I tried and worked.

Example:

```
write-host hi # This is comment

write-host hi `# This is NOT a comment
```

Comment: or enclose the command in single/double quotes. The difference between single and double quotes is that Powershell tries to resolve variables/scripts when between double quotes.